# Which preposition with pleasure, on or in?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is better: pleasure "on" listening to music or pleasure "in" listening?

Comment: You take/find pleasure in listening to music. You derive/get pleasure from listening to music.

Answer (score 1):

With listening to music it is in (or get + while).

I take/find pleasure in listening to music.

I get pleasure while listening to music.

However, with discovering music it is on.

I found great pleasure on discovering music.